# Getting started with Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter Template library

Tags: codeigniter

I'm trying to use [Phil Sturgeon's CodeIgniter Template library](http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show), but I can't get it to change my pages. I read the documentation, followed the steps there,

> 1. Download
> 2. Copy to `application` folder
> 3. Create a `views/layouts/`**`default`** view
> 4. (Auto)load the library

however, it is not clear as to how the template is *actually* implemented. I thought that loading the view would apply the template everywhere, but it doesn't seem to work that way. I've also read about it in the [CodeIgniter Wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Phil_Sturgeon%27s_Template_Library/), but it looked too complicated to be the right answer.

How are you supposed to use Phil Sturgeon's Template with your controllers? (or views?) Am I missing something here?

Comment: For the curious, I've ended up learning [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) and am now much, much happier with it :3

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does not overload the `load->view()` methods, that would be bad. You need to update your controllers to use the template's syntax and methods in every instance you want to use it:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/

You will use `$this->template->build()` instead of `$this->load->view()` in most cases, after constructing your template by defining regions, setting titles, etc.

There should have been a user guide included in your download with examples.

Comment: This is helpful. This was really not clear from the docs or anywhere. Hopefully it'll help other people. But the thing is, I've replaced `load->view('view_name',$data)` with `template->build('view_name',$data)`, but I still see no layout. Did I miss something else?

Comment: Apparently, the default config options do not make the library work out of the box. You have to change the `$config['layout']` paramater to `default` (or your default template name) in `config/template.php` for it to wrap around.

Comment: Does anyone know why the user_guide is down?  http://philsturgeon.co.uk/demos/codeigniter-template/user_guide/  .   Is it no longer supported?  It seems like this is the go-to for CI templating but there are others.